# How to get the hash of a MongoDB document

Tags: mongodb, hash, md5

I'm creating a tool to compare documents in two collections. These collections could be on two different servers.

To make it fast, I'd like to get a hash of each document paired with its _id. Then I take the hashes and compare them to see which documents have been added, removed, changed.

I got it all set up and working, but I was using `db.eval('my code here)`, which has been deprecated and now completely gone.

What are my options using the mongoDB nodejs driver? Tried using mongo shell `mongo --eval ""` that's very OS dependent.

Thanks!